# Warnings on appengine SDK after gcloud updates: Sandbox prevented access to file

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Recently I updated the gcloud SDK and removed the independent appengine SDK. And I have started seeing these warnings

```
INFO     .... stubs.py:50] Sandbox prevented access to file "~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json"
INFO     .... stubs.py:51] If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
```

And these warnings occur when the server is started (and sometimes occasionally)

```
INFO     ... stubs.py:50] Sandbox prevented access to file "/Users"
INFO     ... stubs.py:51] If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
... and this directory error stuff is repeated until it walks upto the app engine root directory...
```

I can suppress these errors in the SDK code, but I wonder - is this is a configuration issue ?

NOTE: The project works, these new warnings make it difficult to scroll through logs. And these logs started showing up without any major code change.

Comment: How are you running the development server (which command and in which dir) and how did you used to do it with the GAE SDK?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I used this both before and after `dev_appserver.py  --port 9181 --admin_port=9111 --host=0.0.0.0 .`